# var check = $("input[no]").is(":checked")?2:1; and how to reach 2nd database row

Tags: javascript, php, post, input, checkbox

Here's the checkbox:

```
$qry_strings4 = "SELECT * FROM `Y new questions`";
$preps4 = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_strings4);
            $preps4->execute();
           // $row = $preps4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo "$count";
            echo "<table style='border:0px; background-color:lightgrey; width:75%'><thead style='border:0px;'><tr style='border:0px solid white; background-color:#153E7E; text-align:left; color:white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Question</th><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Response</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            while ($row = $preps4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightgrey; color:black; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; vertical-align:top; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>{$row['starName']}</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>                
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' name='question' id='{$row['questionID']}' class='response textbox'>{$row['question']}</textarea>";
echo "YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'>
NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            echo "<button type='button' class='save_btn' style='align:right'>Save All</button><br>";
```

Here's the js:

```
$(function(){
  $(".save_btn").on('click', function(){
    //var check = $("input[no]").is(":checked")?2:1;
    var check = $("input[name='no']").is(":checked") ? 2 : 1;
    var questionID = $("textarea").attr('id');
    var question = $("textarea").val();
    $.post("response14.php",{
        //"questionID":$("textarea[name=question]").attr('id'),
        //"question":$("textarea[name=question]").html(),
        "questionID":questionID,
        "question":question,
        "approved":check
    });
      alert("saved");
      location.reload();  
    });
  });
```

Here's the response14.php:

```
include("db_conn.php");
$sql = "update questions set approved = ?, question = ? where questionID = ?";
$qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$qc->execute(array($_POST['approved'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['questionID']));
echo 'Saved<br>';
```

And here's the rendered html:

```
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' name='question' id='3792' class='response textbox'>no</textarea>YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'>
NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'><tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightgrey; color:black; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; vertical-align:top; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Gavin Casalegno</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>                
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' name='question' id='3793' class='response textbox'>yes</textarea>YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'>
NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'></tbody></table><button type='button' class='save_btn' style='align:right'>Save All</button>
```

It is supposed to shows 1 when the yes checkbox is ticked and 2 when the no checked is ticked , but it always shows 1 - that is now fixed

But now I'm unsure what to edit the 2nd database row instead of the 1st one, because there is more than 1 database row to choose from and I can currently only edit the 1st one and not the 2nd one, added more code above to show this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the name properties in the markup, eg `skip name='no[]'`, it is not needed / useless :

```
YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'>
NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>";
```

and use a more accurate selector :

```
var check = $("input[name='no']").is(":checked") ? 2 : 1;
```

and test it :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var check = $("input[name='no']").is(":checked") ? 2 : 1;
    console.log(check);
});
```

Comment: was there `name='no[]'` because there is more than one database to choose from and I can currently only edit the 1st one and not the 2nd one, added more code above to show this

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is looking for an input with a `no` attribute. For your `name` attribute, you have to use this:

```
var check = $("input[name='no[]']").is(":checked") ? 2 : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the syntax:

```
var check = $("input[name='no[]']").is(":checked")?2:1;
```